# UnitOfWork, autofac, Repositories and identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

How can I use Identity in UnitOfWork?
I want the `AccountController`  to inherit from UnitOfWork

Not from

```
IApplicationUserManager userManager,
IApplicationSignInManager signInManager,
IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
IApplicationRoleManager applicationRoleManager
```

I want to use Identity but not from Entity Framework
I did a lot of searches but did not have any results

Answer (score 0):

The only thing your AccountController should inherit is Controller unless you have a base class. Then your base class should inherit Controller and AccountController inherits the base class.

Your UserManager and all the other classes Identity needs to work, need to be registered with AutoFac. It should look something like [this](https://developingsoftware.com/configuring-autofac-to-work-with-the-aspnet-identity-framework-in-mvc-5/), but that article does not talk about using Entity Framework.

To use UnitOfWork with you UserStore, IUnitOfWork will need to be a parameter, and you'll need to tell AutoFac what parameters yous passing. Something like this.

```
    builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserStore>().As<IUserStore<UserMamber>>()
            .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(IUnitOfWork), new UnitOfWork()))
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

**Edit:** Following is the additional code you asked for:

```
public class UserStore<TUser> : IUserStore<TUser, int>
   where TUser : IdentityMember, new()
{
    private UserTable<TUser> _userTable;
    private IUnitOfWork _db { get; set; }

    public UserStore(IUnitOfWork database)
    {
        _db = database;
        _userTable = new UserTable<TUser>(database);
    }
    public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_userTable.Login(userName));
    }
}

public class UserTable<TUser> where TUser : IdentityMember, new()
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public UserTable(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    public TUser Login(string userName)
    {
        var y = _unitOfWork.WebPortalUsers.FindByUserName(userName);

        var Identity = new TUser();
        if(Identity != null)
        {
            Identity.UserName = y.UserName;
            Identity.Id = y.Id;
        }
        return Identity;
    }
}
```